# Kernel of a Character 

Tags: rt.representation-theory, terminology

Why is the kernel of a character equal to the kernel of the representation that affords the character?

Comment: How do you define the kernel of a character? 

Comment: rep, I think your question would be more appropriate at http://math.stackexchange.com (although it seems that Geoff Robinson and David Ben-Zvi have given good answers to it).

Answer (score 7):

This is too elementary a question for MO. In the case of complex characters, the
kernel of a character $\chi$ of a finite group $G$ is $\{g \in G: \chi(g) = \chi(1) \}.$
On the other hand, if the character $\chi$ is afforded by a representation $\sigma$
(that is, $\chi(g) = {\rm trace}(g\sigma)$ for all $g \in G$), then for each $g \in G$,
the eigenvalues of $g \sigma$ are all $o(g)$-th roots of unity, where $o(g)$ is the order
of $g$. Hence the triangle inequality yields $|\chi(g)| \leq \chi(1)$, and the only way 
we can have $\chi(g) = \chi(1)$ is if all eigenvalues of $g\sigma$ are equal to 1. Since $g\sigma$
has finite order, in that case, $g \sigma$ must be the identity matrix. Thus ${\rm ker}\chi$
is precisely equal to ${\rm ker} \sigma$, as the inclusion ${\rm ker}\sigma \leq {\rm ker}\chi$
is clear.

Added later, in light of the discussion below: ``kernel" implicitly refers to the kernel of a group homomorphism here (actually, several group homomorphisms, as we will see). The (complex)
character $\chi$ may be afforded by several different homomorphisms $\sigma: G \to {\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$, where $n = \chi(1)$. But all such representations are equivalent( that is. detemined up to conjugation by a matrix in ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{C})).$ Hence all such representations
have the same kernel in the group-theoretic sense. Furthermore, the argument above shows that the kernel can be seen directly from the character values. Hence the kernel of a character is really the kernel of an equivalence class of representations. One of the (many) advantages of working with (complex) characters is that all normal subgroups of a finite group $G$ can be determined by inspection of the character table of $G$.

It would also be possible to speak of the kernel of an algebra homomorphim, but that would be the set of all elements of the group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$ sent to the zero matrix by a chosen representation $\sigma$, and we would need to consider the algebra homomorphism as mapping into the full matrix ring $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. However, this kernel is not so easy to read from the character values on group elements.

Comment: Yes, this question is too elementary for MO (and may well be a homework problem).   This is standard textbook material: for instance, see pages 23-24 in I.M. Isaacs *Character Theory of Finite Groups* (AMS Chelsea reprint) where it's also explained how to determine other normal subgroups than kernels from a character table.   In some books the treatment is less thorough, e.g., Serre *Linear Representations of Finite Groups* (Exercise 6.7).    

Answer (score 1):

My question is why the kernel of a character $\chi$ of a finite group $G$ is $ \{g \in G: \chi(g) = \chi(1) \} $, instead of $ \{ g\in G: \chi(g) = 0 \} $?

Comment: Because the former matches up with the kernel of the representation while the latter doesn't!

Comment: I have to say that when I first came across this (standard) terminology a few months ago, I found it a little hard to adjust to. So your question is natural.

Comment: Because the fact that the trace is zero does not imply that the matrix is zero (examine the regular representation).

Comment: Characters are not homomorphisms. 

Comment: I think Mark and Qiaochu's comments miss the point slightly. Given a complex-valued function, it is (as we all know) customary to use the word "kernel" for the set of elements in the domain on which the function has the value zero. If, like me, you work mainly in analysis but dabble in algebra, then talk of the "kernel of a character $\chi$" causes momentary cognitive dissonance, since I am used to thinking of characters as elements of $L^2(G)$.

Comment: Is it? I have only seen the term used for group or ring homomorphisms. In general there's no reason to single out the preimage of $0$. 

Comment: If the purpose of defining the kernel of a character is to match up with the kernel of the representation, why don't we simply call it "the kernel of the representation that affords it, and write it as $ker (\Chi)$ instead of $ker (\chi)$?

Comment: @rep: because that would take longer and require an extra symbol? 

Comment: This discussion seems a little besides the point, since characters are MULTIPLICATIVE objects, so you would expect the kernel to be the inverse image of 1 not 0 (as indeed it is for irreps of abelian groups, when the character is just a group homomorphism to the multiplicative group).

Comment: (obviously it's not the inverse image of 1 for higher dim reps, but that would be the first naive expectation). Also note that group characters and Chern characters are examples of the same notion, and the latter explicitly involves an exponential.

Comment: I was not intending to miss the point - there is a natural, but incorrect, intuition here, coming from a particular point of view. The regular representation is a simple example to show why the intuition is wrong. By such examples, in my experience, is the intuition retuned to the correct wavelength.

Comment: (If we ever get these things written up into a paper, I plan to follow rep's suggestion, FWIW, and talk about "the kernel of $\pi$" being the set where $\chi_\pi=1$.)

Comment: [deleted earlier comment which mis-spoke] @Qiaochu, @David, @Mark: hmm, you may have a point. I still think that the OP's question/puzzlement over the terminology is more natural than you guys evidently do.